# How to rent an appartment in Germany as a fresh settler?

Tags: germany, accommodation, rental, job-hunting

When I've arrived to Germany, the first thing I've need to do was to search for an appartment. What striked me, was hard for me to comprehend 'excentrity' of the landlords who required job contract (ehm, why is it important? better ask how much money I have on side...). It wasn't a problem for me because I've already got a job. But...

Consider typical expat situation. You want to settle in Germany. You come there to look for a job. You need an appartment... So how should you look for it to go over that 'job contract' requirement?

Is this 'additional requirement' a standard at all, or was it only a regional variation (Bavaria) or I simply had 'strange luck' when searching for appartment?

Comment: Such requirements are not uncommon in other countries.

Comment: I'm not sure about Germany, but in Belgium your rights as a landlord are ridiculous ... Once a tenant moves in it's really hard to get rid of him, even if he trashes the place or doesn't pay rent. So of course a landlord wants to make sure he's not going to get ripped off ;)

Comment: @CustomX so in that case, that custom would be caused by [controversial] law regulations, and therefore likely to be widespread? And I shouldn't blame landlords but government for such 'warn' welcome?

Comment: As a tenant, why would you be against strong tenant protection laws?  I don't think I've ever seen a landlord who would rent a place to someone without a steady source of income.  How were you planning to pay your rent if you don't have a job yet?

Comment: @gerrit because they are effectively not protecting tenants, they make searching more difficult and prices higher. It's not my definition of protection. Everyone (should) have some spendings, and going abroad for job search may be a good investment.

Comment: @РСТȢѸФХѾЦЧШЩЪЫЬѢѤЮѦѪѨѬѠѺѮѰѲѴ, exactly. I've heard far too many stories of tenants not paying anymore, trashing the place up and as a landlord you can't do sh*t ... Even if you come from abroad, same rules apply. You can view it broader and look at it as accepting that countries culture.

Comment: @CustomX: The law in Germany (generally) favours tenants over landlords, and most tenancy agreements are unlimited (i.e. valid indefinitely), so the same argument applies to Germany. It's very common for landlords to dig deep into the pasts of their prospective tenants, as once the lease is signed it's very hard to get rid of them.

Comment: Please see some tips for renting in my answer to another question: https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/13852/13223